# Integration by part on a surface

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Let $f$ be a smooth positive function from $\mathbb{R}^3$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Can we "simplify" the integral
$$
\int_{\mathbb{S}^2} \dfrac{\Delta f(x)}{f(x)} d \sigma(x),
$$
where $\Delta f$ is the three-dimensional Laplacian of $f$. For instance, what nice conditions on $f$ ensure that this integral have a sign?

Comment: What is the meaning of "this integral have a sign"?

Comment: For, instance, if $f > 0$ and is subharmonic, then $f^{-1} \Delta f > 0$, and the integral is positive. If $f < 0$ is superharmonic, then $f^{-1} \Delta f < 0$, and the integral is negative.

So I rephrase my question as follows: assume $f$ smooth positive and goes to zero at infinity. Is there $R > 0$ large enough so that $$ \int_{R \mathbb{S}} f^{-1} \Delta f \le 0.$$